# WordPress wpautop Not Working Inside Wrapper

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

## Background

I am extending TinyMCE in the WordPress visual editor, and have added a button to wrap selected content in `<section></section>`, which is used on the front-end of my theme for a hero element.

---

## Problem

When I wrap text inside `<section>` tags, wpautop stops running. The `<p>` tags aren't added at all, which breaks things when the selection is multiple paragraphs worth.

#### Example:

This text is in the Text editor (not visual editor).

```
<section>This is paragraph one. This is paragraph one.
This is paragraph two. This is paragraph two.</section>
```

On the front end of the site, it should become:

```
<section><p>This is paragraph one. This is paragraph one.</p>
<p>This is paragraph two. This is paragraph two.</p></section>
```

No `<p>` tags are added though.

## What I've Tried:

I've tried forcing the issue by putting in breaks myself, but they all just get removed.

```
var output = '<section><article>' + text + '</article></section>';
var output = '<section><article><p>' + text + '</p></article></section>';
var output = '<section><article><br>' + text + '</br></article></section>';
var output = '<section><article>\n' + text + '\n</article></section>';
var output = '<section><article>\n\n' + text + '\n\n</article></section>';
```

No matter what I try, the new lines are slowly destroyed.

### [image]

## Question

Is there a way to force `wpautop` to run on content that already has another wrapper?